# KVL On A Circuit With 2 Voltage Sources

Tags: voltage, kirchhoffs-laws, circuits

I want to apply Kirchhoff's Voltage Law on the circuit showed below. When I apply it, I form this equation : $$-20 + Vx - 3Vx - 6i = 0$$

However, my book forms this equation:

$$ Vx + 3Vx + 6i - 20 = 0 $$

What mistake am I doing here ? I'm assuming clockwise current flow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvbbK6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Define how current i runs by adding arrows on every trace between every component (maybe bit overdone) and assign the corresponding + and - to each resistor.

Comment: Remove + Vx - for now. And apply *your own* + and - according to this [picture](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/learn/fundamentals/circuits/voltage-current-characteristics/fig_1.png)

Comment: Your signs for R1 are not correct. Plain said: where the current enters the resistor should be +. Do remove the + Vx - from R2 (we need it later) and call this voltage \$V_{R2}\$ for now apply the correct signs here as well.

Comment: After having defined \$V_{R2}\$ check whether it has the same polarity as how Vx is defined. (It has). Note that the signs around Vx determine how Vx is measured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign of the source is drawn incorrectly or the polarity of how \$V_x\$ is defined should be reversed.

And most likely the equation is correct.

$$ Vx + 3Vx + 6i - 20 = 0 $$

together with the relation
$$ V_x=3\cdot i$$

yields

$$ 18i - 20 = 0 $$

If it were
$$ Vx - 3Vx + 6i - 20 = 0 $$
it would yield
$$ -20=0$$

Comment: I have suspected the same thing but I simultaneously made the resistor polarity mistake. This book has many mistakes. You all have been really helpful.

Comment: @NickDelta The book title is?

Comment: Fundamentals of Electric Circuits 4th edition - Charles K. Alexander , Matthew N.O Sadiku . But maybe it isn't their fault because the book is translated in Greek and maybe these mistakes have occurred in the translation process.

Comment: How would you translate + and - ?? :-D

Comment: I think the polarity of Vx should have been reversed. Because that way, the additional difficulty is the student should take into account that \$V_{R2} = - V_x\$ and the equation becomes $$ 3i - (-9i) + 6i - 20 = 0 $$

Comment: The schematic was wrong in this circumstance. I guess that when my publishing house transformed the schematics to match the style of the book, made that mistake. Nevertheless, it is a sad fact that this is 4th edition and there are so many mistakes.

Comment: @NickDelta And the problem number is?

Comment: @G36 Chapter 3 Example 3.4 in my book

Answer (score 0):

Resistors do not decide about the polarity. The current direction determines the resistor voltage drop polarity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUBI63.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Very good answer, made a crucial mistake there but there's got to be something more as still that's not exactly what my book says. With your fix the equation becomes: $$-20+Vx-3Vx+6i=0$$ which is still not correct. Am I missing something in the polarity of the sources ?

Comment: I think the book is wrong. The sign of \$3V_x\$ is incorrect.

Comment: It seems that this is the case. The book shows the wrong polarity of a VCVS.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. What you state is true **only if** the value of the current and the value of the voltage are positive. When analyzing circuits we usually have to **assume** some particular direction of current flow and/or **assume** a direction of voltage polarity, and then solve the circuit. If any current or voltage turns out to be negative then the **actual** direction of the current or voltage is the opposite of what was assumed. But it is **perfectly legal** to assume that current enters the negative end of a resistor voltage.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Your remark confuses me. I thought the direction of (conventional) current is defined as the same direction as **positive** charges flow. So, drawing an arrow indicates the direction of a **positive** current. Is this correct? Or can the current have any sign independent of the direction of the drawn arrow?

Comment: Yes, the direction of current is the direction of positive charge. You are correct, the value of the current can have any sign independent of the direction of the arrow. Sometimes we don't know which way the current flows, so we **arbitrarily** draw an arrow and write equations based on the drawn arrow. If the value turns out to be negative it just means that current is actually flowing in the opposite direction.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I always stick to this (wrong?) definition: the arrow always **defines** the **positive** charges flow, so the arrow points in the direction of a positive current. So, you cannot draw an arrow and **arbitrarily** pick the sign of the corresponding current. What is the use of an **arrow** if the current could be flowing in both directions? What does the arrow indicate?

Comment: Regarding my definition: I **arbitrarily** (as in educated guess) draw arrows (and fixing the current sign that way) and when the evaluation of the circuit gives a conflict, I reverse the arrow.

Comment: @Huisman I also stick (follow) to this convention. I arbitrarily choose the current direction and based on this assumed direction I "automatically" know the "voltage polarity" across the resistor.

Comment: @Huisman What if a current can change direction over time? If you keep changing the direction of the arrows it becomes very difficult to describe the behavior of the circuit mathematically and be consistent. Allowing for negative voltages and currents makes it possible to analyze more complex circuits. How do you think SPICE handles something like this?

Comment: @Huisman See for example https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312160/calculation-gives-negative-current and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237788/the-sign-of-the-current-flowing-in-a-circuit